# Как обработать response (UTL_HTTP) c вложениями MTOM (xop+xml)?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, httpclient, веб-служба

Есть клиент, который с помощью `UTL_HTTP` делает запрос к веб-сервису и разбирает ответ. Всё работает отлично.

Но в частном случае, сервис может возвращать ответ с вложениями, используя [MTOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Transmission_Optimization_Mechanism).

Ответ моего тестового сервиса, сохранённый в переменной `CLOB`, выглядит следующим образом:

```
--uuid:63178c45-ea9e-424d-b27e-7612f6523dee+id=2
Content-ID: <http://tempuri.org/0>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="application/soap+xml"

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"><s:Header><a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://tempuri.org/IMtomService/GetBytesResponse</a:Action></s:Header><s:Body><ByteResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><Data><xop:Include href="cid:http://tempuri.org/1/636232853596073353" xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include"/></Data></ByteResponse></s:Body></s:Envelope>
--uuid:63178c45-ea9e-424d-b27e-7612f6523dee+id=2
Content-ID: <http://tempuri.org/1/636232853596073353>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

binary data
```

Где binary data - бинарные данные вложения, которые становятся не читаемыми при чтении в `CLOB`. При считывании в `RAW`, опять-таки непонятно, как выделить тело и вложение.

Подскажите, возможно ли вообще отделить в PL/SQL тело запроса от вложения?
Или может есть возможность с помощью Java вызвать какие-либо методы из PL/SQL?

Comment: По количеству строк? По последней строке определять конец заголовка? По моему только парсить ответ.

Answer (score 2):

ТС получил ответ на этот вопрос на сайте [Ask Tom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9533637800346631296):

> We dont have anything native to parse the output, [...]

Никаких функций для работы с WEB сервисами на стороне БД нет.

Одно из решений, поиском ключевых фраз в теле ответа определить, где начинаются бинарные данные вложения, и с этого места читать их как  есть (*RAW*).

Например, как в этом примере:

```
create table resp (created date, text varchar2 (4000), attach blob)
/
declare 
    url constant varchar2 (128) := 'http://example.com/files/xop';
    req utl_http.req;
    resp utl_http.resp;
    line varchar2 (1024);
    text varchar2 (32767);
    buff raw (32767);
    binfound boolean:= false;
    bl blob;
begin 
    req := utl_http.begin_request (url, 'POST', 'HTTP/1.1');
    resp := utl_http.get_response (req);

    begin loop 
        utl_http.read_line (resp, line);
        text := text||line;
        if not binfound then 
            binfound := regexp_count (line, '^Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\s$',1,'m')=1;
        end if;
        exit when binfound and regexp_count (line, '^\s$', 1, 'm')=1;
    end loop; 
    exception when utl_http.end_of_body then
        utl_http.end_response (resp);    
    end;
    
    if binfound then
        dbms_lob.createtemporary (bl, true);
        begin loop
            utl_http.read_raw (resp, buff, 32767); 
            dbms_lob.writeappend (bl, utl_raw.length (buff), buff);
        end loop;
        exception when utl_http.end_of_body then
            utl_http.end_response (resp);    
        end;
    end if;
    insert into resp values (sysdate, text, bl); 
    utl_http.end_response (resp); 
exception when others then
    utl_http.end_response (resp);
    raise;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 2):

Так в БД работа с WEB сервисами затруднительна, то задачу проще решить на другом ЯП с использованием готовых библиотек . Например, на Python с модулем Zepp.

В документации предлагается такой [пример обработки вложений](https://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/attachments.html):

```
from zeep import Client

client = Client ('http://www.risky-stuff.com/claim.svc?wsdl')

pack = client.service.GetClaimDetails ('061400a')

ClaimDetails = pack.root
SignedFormTiffImage = pack.attachments[0].content
CrashPhotoJpeg = pack.attachments[1].content
```

Полученый результат записывать в таблицу с модулем [cx_Oracle](https://oracle.github.io/python-cx_Oracle/).

Есть разные способы организовать "общение" между кодом в БД и внешним для БД кодом: отслеживание изменений в таблице, интер-сессионная коммуникация и т.д.

Или просто вызвать как [внешний скрипт](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/admin/oracle-scheduler-concepts.html#GUID-7072B693-A7CD-4D59-97B8-C25EFB4A2C63):

```
exec dbms_credential.create_credential ( -
    credential_name=>'myunixcred', username=>'iam', password=>'pass')

declare
    jobname varchar2 (30) := dbms_scheduler.generate_job_name;
    script  varchar2 (32767) := 'echo "<<here script text>>"';
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line ('jobname='||jobname);
    dbms_scheduler.create_job (job_name=>jobname, job_type=>'external_script',
        job_action=>script, credential_name=>'myunixcred', enabled=>true);
end;
/
```